# AWS Batch tag EBS volume for cost analysis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am currently developing an AWS Batch processing system with CloudFormation that needs to be analyzed for the total cost of the CFT including the EC2 instances and any IOPS from the EBS volumes. I am performing this analysis based on a tag on the instances and any resources that batch uses. However, my volumes are not being tagged with the same tag as the instances are tagged with. Is there a way with Batch to auto-tag these volumes on creation for cost analysis? Below is the JSON blob from the CFT that creates the compute instance.

```
"ComputeSpot": {
    "Type": "AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment",
    "Properties": {
    "Type": "Managed",
    "ServiceRole": {
        "Ref": "BatchServiceRole"
    },
    "ComputeResources": {
        "MaxvCpus": 500,
        "DesiredvCpus": 0,
        "MinvCpus": 0,
        "BidPercentage" : 50,
        "SpotIamFleetRole": { "Ref": "SpotIamFleetRole" },
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
        {
            "Ref": "SecurityGroup"
        }
        ],
        "Type": "SPOT",
        "Subnets": [
            { "Fn::Join": [",", {"Ref": "Subnets"}]}
        ],
        "ImageId": {
        "Ref": "AMI"
        },
        "InstanceRole": {
        "Ref": "IamInstanceProfile"
        },
        "InstanceTypes": [
        "c3","c5","m5"
        ],
        "Ec2KeyPair": {
        "Ref": "Ec2KeyPair"
        },
        "Tags": {
        "Project": { "Ref": "ProjectTag" },
        "CostRun": { "Ref": "CostRunTag" },
        "Name": {"Fn::Join": ["-", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, "ComputeSpot" ] ] }
        }
    },
    "State": "ENABLED"
    },
    "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
        "id": "ff02a948-912b-4906-9a71-21774f459e87"
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take advantage of IAM to achieve this. As you know, any action that you are doing whether it is from a console, CLI, or CF scripts or anything else invoke internally AWS APIs like CreateInstance or CreateVolume and so on. These API invocations already logged in Cloudwatch. Now all you have to do is the following:

- Configure a new IAM to manage Tagging resources
- Create a new Rule in CloudWatch to invoke a new Lambda AutoTag with the event content
- Inside this lambda, when you receive the event object you will find inside it all the resources ids created by your CloudFormation Stack, tags them all with whatever you are looking for.

For detailed steps, please follow the steps in this URL:
[AWS Solution Page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-tag-amazon-ec2-resources-in-response-to-api-events/)